# What is the scope of the bug where Piecewise breaks DSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, symbolic, piecewise, discontinuity

**Bug introduced after 9.0.1, persisting through 12.3.1. Fixed in 13.0**

---

I have identified a bug in [`DSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html) when differential equation includes a [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) statement with a discontinuity at the boundary.

<s>I want help figuring out how to set the correct border condition for this differential equation that includes a [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) statement with a discontinuity at the boundary.</s>

My tests are in WolframCloud

```
$Version
```

> 12.3.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (May 10, 2021)

The differential system is simple

```
eqns={
  r[0]==0,
  D[r[t],t]== Piecewise[{{a, 0<=t<c}},0] - b r[t]
}
```

Mathematica does find a solution using [`DSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html), but <s>it contains some intriguing results</s> it's the wrong solution.

```
sol=Assuming[
  And[a>0,b>0,c>0],
  FullSimplify[
    r[t]/.First@DSolve[eqns,r,t]
  ]
]
```

[image]

```
nsol=ReplaceAll[sol, {a->1,b->2,c->3}];
Plot[nsol, {t,-1,10}]
```

[image]

First, I would have expected the solution to be a zero constant for $t<0$, here is that I assume I'm not defining the border condition correctly.

Second, there is this term `UnitStep[1-c]`, I don't see how `c==1` is a special condition. I expected this to be `UnitStep[t]`.

<s>How am I supposed to set the border condition for the solution to be zero for $t<0$?</s>

I'm expecting a solution like this

```
Piecewise[
  {
    {(1-Exp[-t b]) a/b, 0<t<c},
    {(1-Exp[-c b]) Exp[-(t-c) b] a/b, c<t}
  }
,0]
```

[image]

Mathematica is giving an incorrect answer and this has been reported to Wolfram Support, acknowledged as a bug, and the developers have been informed.

**Questions:
What is the scope of this problem?
Do other discontinuous functions break `DSolve` too?
Can this problem be reproduced in other versions and platforms?**

Comment: Looks like another bug of `DSolve`. `NDSolve` gives the same result as 2nd graphic.

Comment: I have edited the question, as after communication with Wolfram Support it's clear this is a bug and not a problem on how do I define the border conditions.

Comment: Result in _v9.0.1_ looks correct: `Piecewise[{{(a*(1 - Cosh[b] + Sinh[b]))/b, 
   t == 1 && c > t}, {(a*(-1 + E^(b*c)))/(E^(b*t)*b), c <= t && ((t < 1 && c <= 1) || t > 1)}, {(a - a/E^(b*t))/b, (Inequality[0, LessEqual, t, Less, 1] && (c > 1 || c > t)) || (c > t && 
      t > 1)}, {0, t < 0}}, (a*(-1 + E^(b*c)))/(E^b*b)]`  https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8WaV.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a workaround.

By doing the substituting before calling `DSolve` then it gives the correct solution.

```
ClearAll[r, a, b, c, t];
ic = r[0] == 0;
vars = {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3};
ode = D[r[t], t] == Piecewise[{{a, 0 <= t < c}}, 0] - b r[t];
sol = r[t] /. First@DSolve[{ode /. vars, ic}, r, t]
Plot[sol, {t, -1, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If the substitution is made in the solution afterwards, then yes, it does not give the correct solution.

```
ClearAll[r, a, b, c, t];
ic = r[0] == 0;
vars = {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3};
ode = D[r[t], t] == Piecewise[{{a, 0 <= t < c}}, 0] - b r[t];
sol = r[t] /. First@DSolve[{ode, ic}, r, t];
sol = sol /. vars;
Plot[sol, {t, -1, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Version 12.3.1. windows 10

Answer (score 4):

Fyi, Fixed in V 13.0

[image]

```
Clear["Global`*"]
eqns={
  r[0]==0,
  D[r[t],t]== Piecewise[{{a, 0<=t<c}},0] - b r[t]
}

sol=Assuming[
  And[a>0,b>0,c>0],
  FullSimplify[
    r[t]/.First@DSolve[eqns,r,t]
  ]
]
```

[image]

```
nsol=ReplaceAll[sol, {a->1,b->2,c->3}];
Plot[nsol, {t,-1,10}]
```

[image]